# CSS outline around input element in the form

Tags: javascript, html, css

Does anyone know, is it possible to show outline around input element when user is using sequential navigation (TAB button) and hide outline when user clicks this input element with the mouse? Has anyone implemented this kind of behaviour?

I`m using this property on my :focus selector in CSS file:

```
:focus {
outline: #00bfff solid 1px !important
}
```

Currently, outline appears when input element is focused.

BR,
Raimonds

Comment: Maybe using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Just blur it on click.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('input').on('click', function() {
        jQuery(this).blur();
    });
});
```

This should remove the focus from the input when clicked, thus un-triggering your css rule for `:focus`, while it will still be applied if your input gets the focus by keyboard navigation.

**Edit: Just tried it in Chrome/Windows 7, it doesn't seem to achieve what it is supposed to.**

If someone wants to give it a ride to find a working solution, here's a pen:

> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNMoJv

Comment: you should load jquery in your pen. personnaly i would use the onclick event : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/YXZxVX (your codepen is set onfocus event) both blur() and css() works ;)

Comment: Actually, I cannot add it, since my Chrome crashes the moment I try to.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this either in js or css for js you have to use blur or in css you can use `:focus`. Here is an example of both.

using css 
[**using css in fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/swaranan/32qjkay3/)

using js
[**using js in fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/swaranan/32qjkay3/2/)

for your case use this

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/swaranan/zk1tn481/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hyauyovm/2/

Hope it solves your problem

```
//HTML
<input>
<input>
<input>
<input>


//JS    
<script>

$("input").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('focus');
});

$("input").blur(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('focus');
});

</script>    



//CSS    
input:focus{
    outline:2px solid blue;
}

input.focus{
    outline:none;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this,

```css
input:focus {
outline: #00bfff solid 1px !important
}
```